# Why is platform dependent compilation not working?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, daydream

I'm creating a game for Google Daydream (mobile VR platform) and I use different code to load and save data in editor and in target build. My save function looks like this:

```
public void SaveData() {
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemDatabase));
    FileStream stream;
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    stream = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_data.xml", FileMode.Create);
    serializer.Serialize(stream, gameDB);
    stream.Close();
    Debug.Log("Data Saved[Android]");
#endif
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    stream = new FileStream(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/XML/game_data.xml" , FileMode.Create);
    serializer.Serialize(stream, gameDB);
    stream.Close();
    Debug.Log("Data Saved[Editor]");
#endif
}
```

When I run it in the editor I get logs both for android and editor so both parts are executed. Can this be due to Unity emulating a smartphone(every time I play the game in editor I get this warning: "VRDevice daydream not supported in Editor Mode.  Please run on target device."?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you are in Editor you are also in a specific platform, the one chosen in the build settings.

If you want to run android when not in Editor then you need to say it:

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    stream = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/game_data.xml", FileMode.Create);
    serializer.Serialize(stream, gameDB);
    stream.Close();
    Debug.Log("Data Saved[Android]");
#elif UNITY_EDITOR
    stream = new FileStream(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/XML/game_data.xml" , FileMode.Create);
    serializer.Serialize(stream, gameDB);
    stream.Close();
    Debug.Log("Data Saved[Editor]");
#endif
}
```